# "Quickly using OpenSSL in C" program aborts with core dump

Tags: c

I have a function that aborts with a core dump unless I insert a printf:

```
// Read all available text from the connection
char *sslRead (connection *c)
{
    const int readSize = 1024;
    char *rc = NULL;
    int received, count = 0;
    char buffer[1024];

    //  printf("??"); // If I comment this out: Aborted (core dumped)

    if (c)
    {
        while (1)
        {
            if (!rc)
                rc = malloc (readSize * sizeof (char) + 1);
            else
                rc = realloc (rc, (count + 1) *
                        readSize * sizeof (char) + 1);

            received = SSL_read (c->sslHandle, buffer, readSize);
            buffer[received] = '\0';

            if (received > 0)
                strcat (rc, buffer);

            if (received < readSize)
                break;
            count++;
        }
    }
    return rc;
}
```

The malloc seems to be the offending line.

The full source code is here: [Quickly using OpenSSL in C](http://savetheions.com/2010/01/16/quickly-using-openssl-in-c/)

What could be causing this?

```
Below is the output from my build:

23:06:41 **** Incremental Build of configuration Debug for project HelloWorldOpenSSL ****
Info: Internal Builder is used for build
gcc "-IC:\\dev\\cygwin64\\opt\\cs\\include" -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o MyC.o "..\\MyC.c" 
gcc "-LC:\\dev\\cygwin64\\opt\\cs\\lib" -o HelloWorldOpenSSL.exe MyC.o -lssl -lcrypto 

23:06:42 Build Finished (took 804ms)
```

**EDIT**: The fix I used is posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18861349/1033422).

Comment: Basically AFAIK "C program aborts with core dump unless printf is inserted in code" means access to uninitialized memory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fix the issue, I did the following:

1. Increased the buffer size as mentioned in the [Chris Dodd's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16406/chris-dodd) answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18860789/1033422).
2. While I was debugging, I noticed strlen(rc) to be much bigger than it should be, so I have NULL terminated the rc string before passing it to strcat.

The code *seems* to be working ok now.

```
// Read all available text from the connection
char *sslRead (connection *c)
{
    const int readSize = 1024;
    char *rc = NULL;
    int received, count = 0;
    char buffer[1025];         // increased buffer

    if (c)
    {
        while (1)
        {
            if (!rc)
                rc = malloc (readSize * sizeof(char) + 1);
            else
                rc = realloc (rc, (count + 1) * readSize * sizeof(char) + 1);

            received = SSL_read (c->sslHandle, buffer, readSize);

            if (received > 0)
            {
                rc[count * readSize] = '\0';   // null terminate rc
                buffer[received] = '\0';
                strcat (rc, buffer);
            }

            if (received < readSize)
                break;
            count++;
        }
    }
    return rc;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

```
const int readSize = 1024;
char buffer[1024];
     :
received = SSL_read (c->sslHandle, buffer, readSize);
buffer[received] = '\0';
```

You allocate a buffer of 1024 bytes, then read 1024 bytes into it, and then write a 1025th byte off the end of the buffer...

Comment: I don't think so, there's a `+1` in both `malloc`'s.

Comment: Not to mention setting buffer [received] before checking if `received` is positive...

Comment: @nickie, it's not the malloc'd memory, it's the stack array `buffer`, as  Chris clearly excerpts in the answer.

Comment: @nickie: the mallocs are for `rc` -- they have no effect on the space allocated for `buffer`

Comment: why would the code abort if there isn't a printf statement, but run ok if there is a printf statement?

Comment: @Chris: It's *Undefined Behavior*.  Anything could happen the moment you write that 1025th byte.  The call to `printf()` could be causing the compiler to alter the layout of local variables within the stack frame just enough to change the result from "crash" to "silently corrupting memory", but it's still Undefined Behavior either way.

Comment: Undefined behavior means that an implementation can do anything at all, logical or not.  It could have formatted your hard disk, if you are to believe the C standard...  There's no point looking for reason here, just change 1024 to 1025...

Comment: So should it be `rc = realloc ((count + 1),                     readSize * sizeof (char) );`?